# Django ImageField get username

Tags: django

models.py

```
   def upload_to(instance, filename):
        return 'verify/%s/%s' % (instance.user_idx.username, filename)
    
    class UserVerifyImg(models.Model):
        user_idx = models.ForeignKey(
            User,
            db_column='user_idx',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE
      )
        business_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
        upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    
        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'account_user_verify'
```

This is my model. but It is showed me error.

account.models.UserVerifyImg.user_idx.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: UserVerifyImg has no user_idx.

I don't now what is the problem. help me please.

Comment: Please share full error traceback and a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Have you run migrations after changing in your model?

`python manage.py makemigrations`

Then:

`python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using the right query `instance.user_idx.username` the problem is that at the time you assigning the image path(upload_to) the instance is not created,so that means you can not get `instance.user_idx.username` that is why you are getting that exception.
To solve this problem you can create a foreignkey by doing something like this.

```
class UserVerifyImg(models.Model):
    user_idx = models.ForeignKey(
                User,
                db_column='user_idx',
                on_delete=models.CASCADE
          )
    business_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
        
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'account_user_verify'


def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'verify/%s/%s' % (instance.user_verify_img.user_idx.username, filename)

class Image(models.Model):
    user_verify_img = models.ForeignKey(UserVerifyImg,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
```

1. run python manage.py makemigrations
2. run python manage.py migrate

**Note that You have to change your form and your views for this to work if you need more help let me know**